# Packaging system broken: Error with libqtcore4 package when installing krita (Freya)

Tags: release-freya, package-management

I tried to install Krita via terminal `sudo apt-get install krita` and got an error message. Many packages depend on `libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0)` which is not going to be installed.

I am using elementary OS freya 0.3.2.

Now the problem is that I can't install anything else, I get an error message. The packaging system is damaged.

So far I've tried `sudo apt-get clean`, `sudo apt-get -f install` and also removing and purging krita doesn't work.

When trying to install `libqtcore4` e.g. after `sudo apt-get autoremove -f`, the following error pops up:

`Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` and there is a problem overwriting `'/etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf'`.

Does someone know a solution or can guide me in how to solve this problem?

Comment: krita is most likely for a older or newer version of Ubuntu. Try using the version for Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Can you be more specific what that means to "try to use" an older version? How does it solve the broken package management? Thanks

Comment: Trying to use a old version will try to install old dependencies.

Comment: Try using the instructions @ https://krita.org/download/krita-desktop/

Answer (score 1):

To install the latest and correct Krita on Ubuntu and derivatives (elementary OS) run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install krita
```

This will add the PPA and install Krita.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Maybe because previous versions of Krita must be uninstalled? Unfortunately that is not possible, because the dpks is broken due to dependency issue of libqtcore4 package.

Comment: The error was caused by a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qt4-x11/+bug/1193243). Following comment #2 did do the trick. Now both dpkg and krita work.